# How to access the values using child window handle in C#

Tags: c#

> I am having the handle (IntPtr value) of child window , Any body having any idea how to access its elements using this handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is easy , just use EnumChildWindows to get the handle of the user interface controls.